# Print Positive and Negative Ints With Same Width in Fable

Tags: .net, f#, formatting, printf, fable-f#

I would like formatted integer strings with

- the sign (+/-)
- a width I specify

In .NET,

```
sprintf "%+04i" 1
sprintf "%+04i" -1
```

yields

```
+001
-001
```

but in Fable

```
+001
00-1
```

How do I get the .NET behavior?

Comment: This seems like a bug in the Fable implementation and should probably be an issue on the Fable repository instead.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/1931

Comment: Probably won't work, but do try "d" instead of "i". I don't use Fable, so can't easily check this.

Comment: The issue was fixed and closed!